# Dividing the form into two parts

Tags: forms

I need to put a few input fields in my feedback-form in one part of the page, 
and a few input fields and submit-button in a completely different part of the page, but this  must be the same form that when you click on submit-button data were collected from both the upper fields and from the bottom fields to the one query sent to the server.
How it can be implemented?

Comment: It's too large to put it here.

Comment: just crate a table with two <td>s per <tr> to put your fileds